# function skips 1 of the if condition statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have the following script which checks for varying sizes of an image every time the carousel loads the item and based on its size applies a class. It works for all images but one string within the function.

The string that isn't being read:

```
  if (img.width() == '728' && img.height() == '90' || img.width() == '468' && img.height() == '60') {
      img.addClass('tops');
    }
```

The script:

```
$("#carousel-container-mobile, #carousel-container-desktop").on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
  var imgs = $('.item');
  $(imgs).each(function() {
    var img = $('img', this);
    if (img.width() == '320' && img.height() == '50' || img.width() == '300' && img.height() == '50') {
      img.addClass('top');
    }
    if (img.width() == '728' && img.height() == '90' || img.width() == '468' && img.height() == '60') {
      img.addClass('tops');
    }
    if (img.width() == '300' && img.height() == '250') // 300 x 250
    {
      img.addClass('mid');
    }
    if (img.width() == '120' && img.height() == '600' || img.width() == '160' && img.height() == '600') // 120 x 600
    {
      img.addClass('right');
    }
  });

});
```

All of other images sizes work, but these? not sure why. The syntax seems to be correct, but I feel as it's the markup of the `if` statements?

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/r2wLz6xr/11/

Comment: it seems to work in the fiddle?

Comment: protip: cache those values. Don't call `img.width()` and `img.height()` all the time, set `var w = img.width(), h = img.height()` and make your that bit easier to read. People you ask for help will be glad you've done so.

Comment: You must surround the the && in parentheses in the if && + || combo.

Comment: @Will, why? `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`, which I'm pretty sure is what the code intends.

Comment: @Will not really - `true && true || false && false == true` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: My mistake, I had the && and || reversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because the height & the width has been modified by the carousel to fit the area.

It is `'611' '76'` instead of `'728' '90'`

Have a look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/r2wLz6xr/12/

Comment: Accepting your answer because you were first to point out its the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the width of the container. The width of image is exceeding the width of the container. So image is not getting the total width and `img.width()` is returning value less than `720` for that image.